# CSS/JS show only whole words that fit to the container

Tags: html, css

I've found that article

https://justmarkup.com/log/2015/07/dealing-with-long-words-in-css/

and I'm wondering how to force to display a whole word if it fits to the container:

e.g.

```
some long sentence
```

it can be displayed as

```
some long s...
```

the word `sentence` doesn't fit so I want to hide it and show only:

```
some long
```

my current css (it adds the `...`)

```
.short {
    max-width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Are we talking about character limitation of words in sentence?

Comment: Perhaps you could try using overflow: hidden?

Comment: JavaScript allowed?

Comment: @Bram Vanroy - yes, the JS is allowed

Answer (score 11):

You can try this:

```css
.element{
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">some long string</div>
```

where `max-height`: = `line-height`: × `<number-of-lines>`

Comment: As far as I can tell, you don't actually need `text-overflow: ellipsis` for this effect (and the only effect of `word-wrap: break-word` is to ensure that, if even the first word of the text doesn't fit in the container, it won't get cut off in the middle of a character).

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the text to a certain amount of characters. Then you have to find the last index of a space character and limit the text again using this index.

Here's some example code:

```
function limitText(text, maxLength) {
    if (text.length <= maxLength) {
        return;
    }

    text = text.substr(0, maxLength);

    var lastSpace = text.lastIndexOf(' ');

    return text.substr(0, lastSpace) + '...';
}

limitText('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.', 20);
```

If you only want to limit the number of words you can use this code:

```
var maxWords = 4;
var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.';
var newText = text.split(' ').slice(0, maxWords).join(' ');
```

Comment: in that case there we should get the string length in pixels, not just the chars count

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
div{
white-space: nowrap;
width: 70px;
overflow: hidden;
}
div > p{
white-space: nowrap;
width: 70px;
overflow: hidden;
}

<div><p>some long sentences</p></div>
<div>some long sentences</div>
```

Comment: looks like it doesn't work http://jsbin.com/wunadoyewo/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @Tony provided jsbin link is working perfectly fine in my browser i.e. chrome.

Comment: I was using FIrefox

Comment: Now check that in firefox, try increasing and decreasing your width size in your div or para tag.

Comment: it adds `...` anyway

Comment: @Tony I have remove ellipsis so ... won't be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Simply let the text overflow

```
.short {
  max-width: 250px;
  height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```